# FBX SDK Getting Tangents and Binormals From a Mesh?

Tags: c++, fbx, mesh, import

How do I import **tangent** and **binormal** data per vertex from a **FBX Mesh**.
I already know how to get *Vertices*, *Normals* and *UVs* but how would I get **tangents** and **binormals**?

For example this is how I would get a vertex.

```
int vIndex = MyFbxMesh->GetPolygonVertex(triangle, vertex);
FbxVector4 Vertex = MyFbxMesh->GetControlPointAt(vIndex);
```

What about tangents and binormals?
I searched everywhere on the internet and looked in their documentation but I still can't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [good link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/how-to-work-with-fbx-sdk-r3582) was [given here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74187/directx9-fbx-sdk-and-indices-problem)
 which explains how to get tangents and binormals.

Comment: Thank you for the link it helped me with what I wanted to do and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [the FBX SDK Documentation](http://docs.autodesk.com/FBX/2014/ENU/FBX-SDK-Documentation/index.html?url=files/legal-notice.htm,topicNumber=d30e116) again.  I managed to find `GetElementBinormal(int index)` and `GetElementTangent(int index)`, which are both part of the FBXGeometryBase class, which FBXMesh inherits from.  Have you tried these?  Because, if the documentation is correct (which, given past experiences, I tend to expect the worst, even with wealthier companies' documentation), those should be what you would need, if the data for the tangents and binormals are included with the mesh data.

To extract the data from the objects these methods return, you'll need to use methods found in `FbxLayerElementTemplate< Type >`, namely `GetDirectArray ()` and `GetIndexArray ()`, unless you want to manipulate the actual array, which there are a few methods in that class for that, as well.  You need to look up the inheritance tree with these things, since a lot of the functions will be generalized for multiple class types, and will operate in similar ways on a wide variety of starkly different data structures.

Comment: I did check this but I don't know how to use them. I tried figuring it out but I'm having a hard time. Have you got any idea?

Comment: That entirely depends what you want to do with them.  I found some more info while digging, though.  I'll update the answer.